# How do i take Logs for windows application?

Tags: windows

I am working on an application in Windows 7 environment and the application is not stable yet I wanted to see the crash logs , Please help me to get log files.

Answer (score 0):

> Reporting Services writes event messages to the Windows application
>   log. You can use the message information written to the application
>   log to find out about events that are generated by the report server
>   applications running on the local system.

Reporting Services provides three event sources:

1. Report Server (Report Server Windows service)
2. Report Manager
3. Scheduling and Delivery Processor

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157312.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Log4Net to log errors or alternatively just write your errors to a text file. 
Here is a link on how to use log4net      [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial)